# Inverse differencing of the prediction data LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, lstm

I am doing a time series forecasting with LSTM. When pre-processing the data I did a log-transformation then differencing by a period of 1 and then used MinMaxScaler between 0 and 1.

```
dataset = np.log(dataset).diff()
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

When inverse transforming, I do scaler.inverse_transform, then I put the first value of the original dataset and np.cumsum and np.exp, and it worked completely fine. However, I don't know how to descale my prediction array, because I don't know the first element to do the cumulative sum and just doing np.cumsum is apparently not working.

```
dataset = scaler.inverse_transform(dataset) 
dataset[0] = np.log(dataset_1.iloc[0])
dataset = np.exp(dataset.cumsum()) #Obtained unscaled untransformed original dataset
```

Here is my code, all credit goes to

> https://towardsdatascience.com/5-machine-learning-techniques-for-sales-forecasting-598e4984b109
> https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('airline-passengers.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = np.log(dataset).diff()
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=50, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
```

Here, i have tried doing

```
trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back] = np.reshape(np.exp(np.cumsum(trainPredict)), (len(trainPredict), 1))
testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1] = np.reshape(np.exp(np.cumsum(testPredict)), (len(testPredict), 1))
```

But, apparently, cumsum is not the complete inverse of diff without the shifting, if i don't descale the original data the prediction looks good and i'm amazed at the model working so well. This test here is with a testing dataset, but with the original data, i have R_2 score of 0.8 and lower RMSE for training predictions than testing predicitions which seems like a good fit.

Any help is appreciated.
[Graph of unscaled original data and "unscaled" predicted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiN0D.png)